# Google Sheets Script -> How to copy row as values into another tab based on a cell trigger and then clear the trigger cell?

Tags: google-apps-script

this is my very first attempt at programming period so I apologize for what may come across as a simple question to you experienced folks. I'm working through Google Sheets scripting for this.

ISSUE: I have a file with multiple tabs, the key tabs with this question are marked as "submit" and "db". Within the "submit" tab I will have information (including formulas) in many rows from columns A to Y. When I enter "run" in column Z for a particular row I would like the information in that row only from columns A to Y to copy and paste as values to the next available row in the "db" tab. Once this is complete I would like the original trigger cell to be deleted (not cleared as I have a border around it) and the row above it to be deleted from columns A to Y as well (not cleared as I have borders and data validation)

I hope this makes sense.

Below is the code I've been using. I have been able to successfully move the information from the "submit" tab to the "db" tab but that has been about it. I've been playing with the copyValuesOnly, moveValuesOnly, clearContent, getFormulas/setFormulas however I simply cannot crack the code.

Thank you in advance!

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "submit" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "run") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("db");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,numColumns);

s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.range.clearContent();

}
}
```

EDIT:

I've included a link to the sheet below, hopefully I provided the correct rights to it. As an example of what I want to do is if I were to select "run" in cell Z12 of the "submit" tab it would do the following:

1. copy the information from A12 to Y12 and paste as values to the "db" tab cells A2 to Y2 (as it's the next available row, once this copy is complete...
2. cell Z12 on the "submit" tab (trigger cell) would be would be deleted (border and data validation should remain)
3. the above row from cells D11 to Y11 should be deleted (border and data validations intact)

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VAnFExL7jJVnqvZ_hq_2ihVQFFuV9szCEnT3NLK8m4Y/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this:**

```
function onEdit(event) {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
  var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

  if(s.getName() == "submit" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "run") {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("db");
    var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow()+1,1);
    s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).copyTo(target,{contentsOnly:true});

    //Clear column Z content
    r.clearContent();

    //Clear previous row Column D-Y
    s.getRange(row-1,4,1,22).clearContent();

  }
}
```

**Explanation:**

1. The reason why Sheet "submit" row 12 format and content was cleared is because you are using [Range.moveTo(target)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#movetotarget) to copy the content to sheet "db". moveTo() cuts and pastes (both format and values) from this range to the target range.

   To fix this, you can use [Range.copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options)
2. To clear content of the modified cell (retain data validation and format), use [clearContent()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#clearcontent). Hence to clear the content of modified cell in column Z, use `r.clearContent();`
3. To clear the content of the previous row from column D-Y, get its range first then use `clearContent()`. Done using `s.getRange(row-1,4,1,22).clearContent();`

**Output:**

(Before)

[image]

(After)

[image]

> Notice that the formula is still available in row 12

[image]

Comment: Thank you Ron this worked! To tweak it just a tad do you know how it may be modified to only copy over information from columns A to Y in the row rather than the full row? I'm going to guess it has something to do with either s.getLastColumn() or s.getRange(row,1,1,numColumns)?

Comment: Hi @Paqua17, yes thats correct you need to select the range first using `s.getRange(row,1,1,numColumns)` before copying. By the way I didn't noticed the hidden columns. I updated the column from `s.getRange(row-1,4,1,19).clearContent()` to `s.getRange(row-1,4,1,22).clearContent()`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all you need to do is:

change that last row to

```
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearContent();
```

"s.range" isn't doing anything.

It is unclear, you want to maintain the datavalidation and borders, right?

also unsure whether you were clearing out two rows or one, if it is two

```
s.getRange(row-1, 1, 2, numColumns).clearContent();
```

Does this get you closer?

whole code (added for clarity)

```
function onEdit(event) {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();

if(s.getName() == "submit" && r.getColumn() == 26 && r.getValue() == "run") {
var row = r.getRow();
var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("db");
var target = targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1,1,1,numColumns);

s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).moveTo(target);
s.getRange(row, 1, 1, numColumns).clearContent();

}
}
```

Comment: Yup I do want to maintain borders, data validation and cells in the "submit" tab however the content within these cells should be deleted once moved. If I remove my moveTo(target) portion it will not move the cells selected to the "db" tab. Going to add my file to my original posting...

Comment: don't remove your move to, change the row AFTER that to the one I gave you.

Comment: Alas it does what my previous script had been doing in completely clearing the row (formats and data validation as well).